# Skype version on Mac OS X 10.3.9 Panther

Tags: macos, mac, skype

What is the last version of Skype that runs on a Mac OS X Panther 10.3.9 ?
I've download a so called compatible version but it doesn't start.
I've also heard that it can be a problem coming from Quicktime version...

Comment: So what version did you download?

Comment: Any news ? Does it work now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the bottom of the [download page](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/download/skype/macosx/) :

**System Requirements :**

- Mac computer with G4, G5 or Intel processor,  800 MHz or faster.
- Mac OS X v10.3.9 (Panther) or newer.
- For higher-resolution video a faster processor (Core 2 Duo) and a broadband connection with at least 384kbps upload speeds.
- 512 MB RAM.
- 100 MB free disk space on your hard drive.
- Either a built-in or external microphone is required for voice calls.
- Either USB or regular headset if your Mac does not have a built-in microphone.
- Download drivers if you are using an external webcam.
- Internet connection – broadband is best (GPRS is not supported for voice calls).

**Technical details :**

- Version 2.8.0.851 File size 44 MB. Official release. Release date: February 10, 2010. File name: Skype_2.8.0.851.dmg

The problem is not only the version on Mac OS X, but the hardware requirements.

Does your computer meet them ?